# Udpclient localendpoint, remoteendpoint. What is that mean?

Tags: c#, udpclient

How can i specify specific ipaddress:port for udpclient to receive? im confused with updclient.client.localendpoint and udpclient.client.remoteendpoint. i was thinking maybe its remoteendpoint, but i cannot display remoteendpoint value. plus my local endpoint ip is 0.0.0.0. what is that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.0.0.0 means "any address".  The local endpoint is the IP address and port you will listen for packets on.  The remote endpoint is not required for UdpClient objects.  It only specifies the default host to send a packet to, if you do not specify one when sending the packet.

You can leave the local endpoint as 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen for traffic on all of your assigned IP addresses on all of your network connections.  You only need to change this if you only want to listen on *one* particular address/connection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I think they should name localendpoint as the local ip and remote endpoint as the remote ip and not the other way around. Well, thats just me.

Comment: Well, just an IP address means no port numbers, and you have to listen on a port.  An endpoint in a TCP/UDP-IP network is an IP address and a port.